# Why my Vue.component is not rendered at HTML page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i'm try to create a Vue.component, but HTML page is not render him (chrome does not give a errors). Please tell me where I made a mistake, what I'm doing wrong?

main.js:

```
Vue.component('product-type-component', {
data() {
    return {listProductType: []}
},
beforeMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost/admin/getListProductType')
    .then(response => {
        this.listProductType = response.data
    })
},
template:'<option v-for="index in listProductType" v-bind:value="index.id +  "/" +  index.name">{{index.name}}</option>'
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#mainForm",
    data:{...},
beforeMount(){...},
methods:{...}
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainForm">
    <select v-model="selectItem">
        <product-type-component></product-type-component>
    </select>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script\vue\vue.js"></script>
<script src="script\axios\axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script\main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you able to get any interactivity from Vue? can you start with a basic example?
can you get this example working? https://alligator.io/vuejs/hello-world-vuejs/

Comment: i dont think you can use custom elements inside select

Comment: I think the best way would be to put the <select> inside the 'product-type-component', and pass the property selectItem to it. Maybe this can help you: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think you didnt realize that you add your Vue as a `node` to the `div#mainForm`.

As a sibling the select node is not in scope of your SPA. And furthermore - I am not overall sure - but I think during the mounting process all other nodes are removed from `div#mainForm`

It is more like this you want:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component("product-type-component", {
  data() {
    return { listProductType: [] };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    // axios.get('http://localhost/admin/getListProductType')
    // .then(response => {
    //     this.listProductType = response.data
    // })
  },

  template: "<option " + /* v-for... */ ">some option</option>"
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `<select><product-type-component></product-type-component></select>`
});
```

working sample: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zlor72vv0)

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { METHODS } from "http";
import * as axios from "axios";
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
var productTypeComponent = Vue.component("product-type-component", {
  data() {
    return { listProductType: [] };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all").then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.listProductType = Object.keys(response.data.message);
    });
    console.log("///" + this.listProductType);
  },
  template:
    '<select><option v-for="(item, index) in listProductType" v-bind:value="item">{{item}}</option></select>'
});
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  methods: {},
  template: `<div><product-type-component /></div>`
});
```

Comment: Sorry again, I'm just trying to learn. i'm edit my code, but still vue.component does not show, and console.log(this.listProductType) is empty. New main.js:
    " Vue.component('product-type-component', {
 data() {
  return {listProductType: []}
 },
 beforeMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost/admin/getListProductType')
        .then(response => {
            this.listProductType = response.data
        })
        console.log(this.listProductType)
    },
    template:'<select><option v-for="index in this.listProductType">{{index.name}}</option></select>'
    }); "

Comment: Its fine  - but try using \` to mark  code ;) . Try doing your stuff here  https://codesandbox.io/s/vue so you can share  a link with what you got, and consume any open api  - so every one can follow up in your thoghts;)

Comment: I corrected the mistake, thanks. My Vue.component: https://codesandbox.io/s/zkvl70mqpm?fontsize=14. Now i have a error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: dont use this in template^^